# AWS CloudFormation: Failed to run cfn-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am getting an error "failed to run cfn-init" while running this template:

[aws-hangouts/s3-role-authentication.json at master · amazon-archives/aws-hangouts](https://github.com/amazon-archives/aws-hangouts/blob/master/20140130_cfn/s3-role-authentication.json)

I am not sure how to trouble-shoot such issues in cloud-formation.
How exactly does `cfn-init` work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check the /var/log/cfn-init.log on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

That template will launch an Amazon EC2 instance.

The `cfn-init` configuration will then download `index.html` and `images.zip` from the S3 bucket specified in the template parameters.

You can check the log file in `/var/log/cfn-init.log` or use **Get System Log** in the EC2 console to view errors.

Start by checking that the referenced S3 bucket exists and those two files are in the bucket.